# Ordinary commands do not work in /mnt/

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

I'm Using Ubuntu 12.04, and after some time of inactivity, I can't use `ls` `cp` `mv` o any other command in my `/mnt/` folder, I have to reboot to can do anything in this folder.

Here's my `/etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.


# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/PITCAIRN-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=21089a7e-981e-4b20-b682-596f5099f539 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/PITCAIRN-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
# SHARED FOLDER
//10.0.0.39/D$/ /mnt/charles/ cifs user,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,rw,gid=1000,sec=ntlmv2,credentials=/root/creds 0 0
# SAMSUNG HD502HI
UUID=E238B30638B2D92D /mnt/sdb1/ ntfs rw 0 0
# CD-ROM
#/dev/sr0 /mnt/sr0 udf,iso9660 user,noauto 0 0
```

---

The Windows firewall already has the rules to allow samba and another relative applications but when I activate the firewall it blocks the connection of samba and when I disable it samba returns to live.

Comment: My guess is that it is a problem with the cifs mount. If the server goes down or there are connectivity problems you will see this behavior. I suggest you mount the share only as needed.

Comment: Unfortunally is not a option, I must leave it mounted, and sometime ago this was not happening, so what changed ?

Comment: No one can help me with that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, my Avast! Internet Security was somehow blocking my connections.

To get ride of the problem, you have to enable "Internet Connection Sharing mode".

1. Open Avast!
2. Click the **Firewall** tab
3. Make sure the **Firewall Settings** sub-tab is selected
4. Click **Expert Settings** next to the **Stop** button
5. Check *Internet Connection Sharing mode*
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
7. Close Avast!

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to change this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)